# How to get data from database to dropdown list in angular using REST API

Tags: angular, api, rest, dropdownlistfor

I have created an API for getting all services, I want to put the name of services in dropdown list, I have tested this code but it doesn't work!

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
     <select name="Service" 
      class="form-control">
     <option>-- Select Services --</option>
     <option [value]="serv.service_name" *ngFor="let serv of ServiceList">
       {{ serv.service_name}}
     </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

TS

```
ServiceList: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.serviceService.getAllServices().subscribe((data: any)=>{
  this.ServiceList = data;
  //console.log(this.services);
})  
}
```

It doesn't get data from database !!
[image]

Comment: Is there any errors you can see in developer console (F12)?

Comment: No there isn't, it doesn't get data

Comment: can you show `getAllServices` function of `serviceService ` service

Comment: getAllServices(){
    return this.http.get<any>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/getAllServices/");
  }

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no error in your console, the only reason your dropdown list would be empty is that your `data` is actually an empty array, i.e. `[]`.

Add `console.log(data);` and check what your API returns.

**EDIT:**

According to your comment, your API returns:

```
[{…}] 0: {..., name_service: 'AAAA', ...} length: 1 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

The property is named `name_service` and NOT `service_name` as you are using it in your HTML template...

Comment: [{…}]
0: {id: 8, name_service: 'AAAA', desc_service: 'abcd', price_service: 120}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: @Dev I edited my answer. Please read the EDIT section.

Comment: I have changed it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Dev Update your question's snippet with what you're currently using. Copy-paste your code. Don't type it.